# Fibonacci in Python - Simple solution

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 1
n3 = n1 + n2
for i in range(10):
   n1 + n2
   print(n3)
   n1 = n2
   n2 = n3
```

According to what I know, this should be the simplest way of outputting the first 10 digits of the series, however, it prints `2` 10 times. I don't understand why `n1` doesn't get set to `n2`, and `n2` doesn't get set to `n3` after `n3` has been printed.

Comment: What do you think merely `n1 + n2` means?

Comment: Compare line 5 to line 3 - spot the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. And you should first learn and try as much as you can on your own. I am also a beginner so I know what you are thinking.
For some quick edits to make it workable:

```
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
n3 = 0
for i in range(10):
   n3 = n1 + n3
   print(n3)
   n1 = n2
   n2 = n3
```

1. The series starts with 0, you initialized it with 1.
2. The update statement `n3=n1+n2` is outside the loop, how will it update? What is happening here is `n3 = 1 + 1 = 2` in your code stays the same and it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

```
n1 = -1
n2 = 1
n3 = n1 + n2
for i in range(10):
    n3 = n1 + n2
    print(n3)
    n1 = n2
    n2 = n3
```

This should work. You failed to store sum of n1 and n2.
You are simply printing n3 ie 2 ten times.
And try initiating n1 and n2 from -1.